# Hyperlinking the full citation, not only the number

Tags: hyperref, citing, back-referencing

I want to make the whole citation a link to the corresponding bibliography entry, instead of just the number.

I want also to make the optional argument of `\cite` part of this link.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}         
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
By \cite[Theorem2.1]{4}, the A-covariance operator

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} {Outgrowths 
of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I would like that the result of the `\cite` command would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *like this*? The color? The number? Can you clarify, please?

Comment: The  color in  the  number  and  in  the  word theorem  not only in  the  number

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I hope that the number of the reference and the word Theorem 2.1 will be colored.

Comment: I made something. It's not pretty but it works. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Thank you. Why it is not pretty? I hope only to change the color like the picture.

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little research and didn't find any way of doing what you want with an out-of-the-box method.

I made something, but it's not pretty and errors may occur.

(Almost) as Donald Knuth said:

> Beware of bugs in the below code; I have only tested it, not proved it correct.

:P

I defined a new command `\ccite`. It *should* work exactly like the standard `\cite` command. The `\ccite` command is a wrapper for the actual `\cite` command which calls the latter inside a `\hyperlink`.

The `\hyperlink` uses the `cite.<citation-name>` tag to make the hyperlink to the bibliography and attaches the link to the `\cite` command.

The `\ccite` command works with the optional argument of the `\cite` command, and also works in case the bibliography is built with bibTeX. I haven't tested it with bibLaTeX though.

*Note:* Since the hyperlinking is made with a citation command *and* with a linking command, the color of the full citation is given by both the `citecolor` and `linkcolor` option of `hyperref`.

So, here it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{HTML}{617BAC}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\def\ccitecolor{red}
\def\ccite{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@@ccite}{\@ccite}%
}
\def\@@ccite[#1]#2{%
  \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\cite[#1]{#2}}%
}
\def\@ccite#1{%
  \hyperlink{cite.#1}{\cite{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

By \ccite{4}, the A-covariance operator

By \ccite[Theorem 2.1]{4}, the A-covariance operator

By \textcolor{citeblue}{\cite[Theorem 2.1]{4}}, the A-covariance operator

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} {Outgrowths 
of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, How can I add a link to a paper in thebibliography? I hope that the link doen't appear after compilation

Comment: This is an example: \bibitem{14}{ S. Fornaro and A. Rhandi,}{On the Ornstein Uhlenbeck operator perturbed by singular po- tentials in $L^p$-spaces: }Discrete and Contin. Dyn. Syst. Ser. A 33 (2013) 5049-5058. http: //dx.doi:10.3934/dcds.2013.33.5049.

Comment: You want to create a link to the DOI? Then use the `\href` command. The syntax is `\href{url}{text}`. `url` is the link to the website and `text` is the text that will be linked.

Comment: Yes. I hope that you give me an example because it doesn't work

Comment: If the site could be linked directly, you could use `\url`, for example: `\url{www.google.com}`. But the DOI is not a "valid" url, so you have to link to the corresponding website. Use this: `\href{http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2013.33.5049}{http://dx.doi:10.3934/dcds.2013.33.5049}`

Comment: Dear Professor, please the color that you defined `\definecolor{citeblue}{HTML}{617BAC}` seems to me not very clear. How can I modify it to `dark blue` or red or other clear color? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When I replace `\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}` by `\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}` it is fine, however with `\hypersetup{urlcolor=darkblue, citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue}`  it doen't compilates.

Comment: @Student It doesn't compile because the color `darkblue` does not exist (by default). Instead of changing the color name you can change the definition of the `citeblue` color and use, for instance, `\definecolor{citeblue}{HTML}{102F71}`. The "`102F71`" is the HTML color code, which I got from [this site](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/) (there are many others as well). You can define your color and change it with the HTML code. P.S.: I'm not a professor, I'm a student as well :)

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. For example the color Navy, how can I define it? It is written in the site `#000080 RGB(0, 0, 128)`

Comment: I don't understand how can I get the HTML color code of a given color? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student Sorry for the late reply, I was traveling yesterday. The HTML color code is a 6-digit (hexadecimal) code, usually with a `#` in front of it, in your case, it's the `#000080` so you can use `\definecolor{citeblue}{HTML}{000080}`. You can use the RGB code as well, with `\definecolor{citeblue}{RGB}{0,0,128}`.